# Links on the FAQ page are not underlined

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Links on the FAQ page do not appear underlined like everywhere else

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq

[image]

Comment: this will push w the next build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been changed so that links in the div class .content-page also have underlined treatment.

.post-text is the other site wide class.

both should match.